# KVM virtualization issue

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I'm finding difficult regarding KVM issue.

I need to create an emulator in my Android Studio. Thus, I have to enable virtualization in my CPU.

Virtualization is enable in the bios of my laptop, but it still says:

> KVM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found. Enable VT-x in
>   your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working
>   KVM module.

I have installed KVM also

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
```

I have latest KVM.

Comment: This is a **Q&A** site, and quite a few people are here to help **A**nswer other peoples' **Q**uestions. Other people might just come for existing answers as their question was already posted here. But your post has no question, so it doesn't really belong on this site. Do you want to know if other virtualization techniques are easier to get working?

Comment: Have you tried commands showin in `HINT` section?

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial: [Speeding Up the Android* Emulator on Intel® Architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture)

You need section [2.3.1. Installation of KVM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture#_Toc358213273)

And:

> The next step is to install the KVM and a few other packages needed.
>   To do so, type
>
> sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder
>   bridge-utils

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution for the problem, a simple and a good.

- The simple solution: use an android/arm emulation, it doesn't need kvm (but it will be slow).
- The good solution: nearly all of the today's CPUs *have* VT-x emulation, if your laptop is enough strong for the Android Studio, it surely has one.

  - Check your laptop bios, and turn it on.
  - Check your kernel, if the kvm device exists.
  - If it doesn't, then `modprobe kvm`.